# How to convert datetime index of matplotlib to month

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

I have made this graph in matplotlib notebook magic. I want to convert the datetimes into months as they seem messy like this. What to do?

[image]

Comment: I'd use a date formatter like concisedateformatter https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html or the other choices at https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/dates_api.html.  Maybe the title should be changed, since you are formatting dates, not converting them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) module:

```
import datetime
x_values = [d.strftime("%b %y") for d in dates]
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
```

Which outputs `Jan 15` instead of `2015-01`. If you want to plot the full year and month name, you can use `"%B %Y"`.

Comment: That will give a string and tick for each data value, which is almost certainly not what is wanted.

Comment: Could you explain in detail what is not working @SeamAhmed?